# Manga about a woman who has pink hair and can see ghosts

Tags: story-identification, manga

The female lead has eyes that are either pink or gold — I can't remember well — and she has pink hair. She can see ghosts and, on her way to her college orientation, she bumps into a guy. The guy she bumps into had a spirit tied to him that can kill/ward off the ghosts. Her friend can also see them, I think, and the male lead lives right next door to her. I can't remember much else.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour?

Comment: yes it was in full colour

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark their answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: oh okay thank you for letting me know

Comment: But does the story have any fantastical elements? I'm sure there are lots of people in the real world who have pink hair and can see ghosts.

Answer (score 4):

I found this post while looking for this story and I’m like 80 percent sure you’re looking for [The Mirage That Reaped at Night](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/wcuqkpf/the-mirage-that-reaped-at-night):

> Born as a spirit medium, Tae-nam has lived and escaped ghosts. She lived a limited life under the protection of her grandmother, a shaman, but she finally found her freedom when she went to a university.
>
> In addition, the guardian spirit of a person, whom she met at the entrance ceremony, is a god with general-level ability to exorcise the surrounding ghosts, and will Tae-nam enjoy free college life with holiness?

[image: FMC seeing ghosts at school]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you describe this work some more so it's possible to see how well it matches the question?

Comment: I believe this also goes by the name "To You Who Protects". If I'm correct that's the name manga database websites are using for it.

Answer (score 3):

This matches *[Half-Ghost](https://m.webtoons.com/en/romance/half-ghost/list?title_no=2765&page=1)*, a freely available Webtoon, except for some details. It is a full-color manhwa where the female lead has pink hair and pink eyes and can see ghosts (well, kinda). She makes some friends who can see ghosts (because they *are* ghosts), including the male lead (the titular half ghost) who often kills or wards off other ghosts. Both leads are college students.

Not convinced it's a match, but still worth mentioning.

Answer (score 2):

*[Mieruko-Chan: The Girl That Sees "Them"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mieruko-chan)*

> High school student Miko Yotsuya has the unfortunate ability to see horrifying ghosts and spirits that haunt her and the people around her. Despite this, Miko does her best to ignore the existence of ghosts and tries to live out a normal high school life.

Miko has golden eyes. [Julia](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Characters/MierukoChan) has pink highlights in her hair and can see the ghosts. Zen might be the fellow you are thinking of who's followed by a spirit that wards off other spirits, although he's a teacher, she doesn't meet him during college orientation, and the spirit following him is his mother, who actually kills cats around him.

Found with a search for `manga girl can see ghosts pink hair`

Comment: Admittedly, this mixes around a lot of the details, and the pages I've found in Japanese are black-and-white although the covers are in color.

Answer (score 1):

*[A Fortune-Teller Princess](https://myanimelist.net/manga/163177/A_Fortune-Telling_Princess)*

[image: Cover image, showing protagonist with pink hair]

> Top actress Lee Sia has the ability to see ghosts. After an accident, she wakes up in the body of 'Camilla Sorfelle'. But here's the problem. "Oh, Father, help me!". This woman's fate always end in death! I need to extend my life, so might as well talk to the ghosts first. Ugh, but why do I keep getting involved with people I want to avoid!?

Camilla Sorfelle has pink hair and has been able to see ghosts ever since she was small. Arsian Sephra is another student who attends the same academy as Camilla. He is not her neighbour. Camilla is interested in forming a business relationship with Arsian because of his black mana and his ability to process black rock from her mines so that anybody can use it. Camilla solicits help from ghost Amy to meet up with Arsian. Amy fears Arsian stare stating it feels like it can exterminate her. Arsian reveals that he can only see a black mist and not the ghosts themselves and is not able to talk to them. He declares that he is aware of a ghost that has been shadowing him for 10 years. Arsian says he can dispel/destroy that ghost but chooses not to. Camilla later identifies that ghost to be Arsian's dead brother Ciel.

Comment: What other details does this match? For example, what about the neighbor and college?

Comment: According to my anime list, "Published: Sep 27, 2023"; over a year after the question was asked.

Comment: @qazmlpok myanimelist does lack detail and has at least one error (it says the title is Japanese, when, it's Korean). Also, whilst the OP does mention manga we can't completely rule out that the OP may have seen the web novel instead. On the novelupdates, the Korean web novel is dated 2022.

Comment: @Laurel your feedback prompted me to update the answer.

Comment: [Manga Updates](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/6hrii6o/a-princess-who-reads-fortune) also says the manhwa was released in 2023. [Novel Updates](https://www.novelupdates.com/series/a-fortune-telling-princess/?pg=3#myTable) lists the first chapter of the web novel as having been released on July 23 2022, which is still (slightly) after this question was posted.

Comment: @LogicDictates fair point. However, after digging deeper I found a Korean [blog](https://m.blog.naver.com/seoju_97/222779116013) that says serialization began on June 3rd, 2022.